# Can I take new driving test

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, driving-license, driving

I am a English Driving instructor. I will move to Germany on December 2022. Can I use/work with my English Car Driving instructor in Germany

Comment: It is not at all clear what is being asked here. An English Driving instructor, that moves to germany cannot automaticly start working as a Driving instructor. They must have a Fahrlehrerlaubnis (Fahrlehrerschein) if they fulfill the conditions of [§21 Fahrlehrergesetz (FahrlG) Voraussetzungen für die Erteilung der Fahrschulerlaubnis bei Inhabern eines Befähigungsnachweises aus einem anderen Staat](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/fahrlg_2018/__21.html) (German only).

Answer (score 2):

Driving instructors in Germany must have themselves cleared the driving test for all possible vehicles types. I think it is highly unlikely that they recognise your instructor card from there without giving you any trouble. The commend from Mark Johnson gives you the link to get started to find out.

You may be able to use your driving license to get a German one to drive around, but not teach with it.

Comment: When you say "Driving instructors in Germany must have themselves cleared the driving test for all possible vehicles types." - does that mean somebody who teaches teenagers how to drive passenger cars must have a motorcycle license, a bus license, and an articulated lorry license?  Or did you mean "... must have passed the driving test for each vehicle type they wish to teach"?  (Which is rather different - they probably want a normal car license, and a caravan/trailer license - but not necessarily the rest.)

Comment: Option 1: all of them!